# Assigning events to multiple dynamic labels

Tags: excel, vba, events, dynamic, label

In VBA I struggle to assign events to labels that are created dynamically. I want to assign tbEvents_Click to every label.

I have the class Class1

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents tbEvents As MSForms.Label


Private Sub tbEvents_Click()
   
        MsgBox "You clicked label"

End Sub
```

and the form frMain

```
Dim HH As Long, VV As Long

Public tbPin As MSForms.Label
Dim Question As New Class1

Dim objMyEventClass As New Class1
  


Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    HH = shQuestions.Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    VV = shQuestions.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
  
End Sub

Private Sub addQuestions()


    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim mmm As String

    For i = 1 To VV + 1
        
        For j = 1 To HH + 1
    
        Set tbPin = frMain.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "label" & i & j, True)
            
            With tbPin
                              
                If i = 1 Then
                    .Caption = "Question" & i & j
                    .Height = 80
                    .Top = 230
                    .BackColor = RGB(100, 116, 168)
                    
                Else

                    .Caption = "labelPoints" & i & j
                    .Height = 460 / VV
                    .Top = 310 + (i - 2) * (460 / VV)
                    .BackColor = RGB(0, 116, 168)                 

                End If

                           
                If j = 1 Then
                    .Caption = "Points" & i & j
                    .Width = 325
                    .Left = 50
                    .BackColor = RGB(100, 116, 168)
                    
                Else

                    .Width = 750 / HH
                    .Left = 375 + (j - 2) * (750 / HH)
                                       
                    Set objMyEventClass.tbEvents = tbPin

                End If
                
            End With
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

I was hoping that

```
Set objMyEventClass.tbEvents = tbPin
```

would assign the event to all labels. But it only adds the event to the last created label. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating multiple instances of `Class1` (one for each label) so you need to store those somewhere like a Collection, so they can all stay in scope once your  `addQuestions` sub is done.

Here's a simplified example

Class1:

```vb
Public WithEvents lblEvents As MSForms.Label

Private Sub lblEvents_Click()
    MsgBox "You clicked label " & lblEvents.Caption
End Sub
```

Userform:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim Questions As Collection 'needs to hold >1 Class1 object

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    addQuestions 10, 10
End Sub

'create and return an instance of Class1
Function getLabelHandler(lbl As MSForms.Label)
    Set getLabelHandler = New Class1
    Set getLabelHandler.lblEvents = lbl
End Function


Private Sub addQuestions(numRows As Long, numCols As Long)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, lbl As MSForms.Label
    Set Questions = New Collection

    For r = 1 To numRows
        For c = 1 To numCols
            Set lbl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblR" & r & "C" & c, True) 'Me
            Questions.Add getLabelHandler(lbl)
            lbl.Caption = "R" & r & "-C" & c
            lbl.BackColor = IIf(r = 1 Or c = 1, RGB(100, 116, 168), RGB(0, 116, 168))
            lbl.Top = 20 + (r - 1) * 20
            lbl.Left = 20 + (c - 1) * 40
            lbl.Height = 19
            lbl.Width = 39
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```